# How to build from one of the image sets without bloating the apk size in flutter?

Tags: android, flutter, flutter-dependencies

I have different set of images for different apk's I'm building but it's all done within a single code base and I'll be using only one set of images for a specific apk. So I'm wondering if including all the image assets in pubspec.yaml will increase the build size of the app ? If it increases, is there any way to conditionally import the images at build time ?

Answer (score 1):

This is currently not directly supported by Flutter.

Related issues

- https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/8230
- https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/21682
- https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/16816
- https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/15486
- https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/5813

As a workaround I use a custom build script that invokes `flutter build ...`
but before that modifies some symlinks within `assets/...` so that the required set of assets is linked to the path listed in `pubspec.yaml`

Comment: Thanks but I'm kind of new to Flutter. Can you please point me to articles or links that can help me get started with flutter custom build process ?

Comment: I'm not aware of articles about that. It's just a bash script that changes a directory to forward to another directory before it executes `flutter build ...`